# Accessing the properties of an object of an object dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, object, properties

Given that I'm getting different object results depending of the API I query, here are two examples out of 35 I have to implement:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [mid] => 7127.75
    [bid] => 7126.6
    [ask] => 7128.9
    [last_price] => 7128.8
    [low] => 7000.0
    [high] => 7492.1
    [volume] => 53255.4195502
    [timestamp] => 1510265647.9803913
)


stdClass Object
(
    [Success] => 1
    [Message] =>
    [Data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [AskPrice] => 7095
            [BidPrice] => 7070
            [Low] => 7001
            [High] => 7540
            [Volume] => 17.38943459
            [LastPrice] => 7090
            [Change] => -1.02
            [Open] => 7163
            [Close] => 7090
        )

    [Error] =>
)
```

I want to build mapping variable array to access the object easily.

```
$xmap["a"]["bid"] = "bid";
$xmap["b"]["bid"] = "Data->BidPrice";
```

Let's assume $content has the first example object, this will work:

```
print $content->{$xmap["a"]["bid"]};  // the result is 7128.9
```

As for the second example object, it does not:

```
print $content->{$xmap["b"]["bid"]};  // the result is PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$Data->BidPrice in ...
```

Can this be done or am I stuck with if statements!

Comment: Make a model/s, dont use the same code for both, problem solved. Are these 2 different APIs? If so create an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert all the objects into assoc. arrays by using json_encode/decode. You'll find this code multiple times here in stackoverflow

```
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);
```

Second, I recommend a dot-notation for the key-path, plus a tiny function to find the value in a multidimensional array.
Example:

```
function fromArray($key, $arr) {
    $keys = explode('.', $key);
    foreach($keys as $k) { 
        if (!isset($arr[$k]))
            return array(); // return empty array
        $arr = $arr[$k];
    }
    return $arr; // can be a scalar value or array
}

$key = 'my.super.array.content';
$array = ['my' => [
            'super' => [
                'array' =>[
                    'content'=>4711
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

var_dump($array, fromArray($key, $array));  
/*
array(1) {
  ["my"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["super"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["array"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["content"]=>
        int(4711)
      }
    }
  }
}
int(4711)
*/
```

I found the dot-notation very useful when dealing with complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

You  can convert your objects to arrays and build a large mapping array that needs to be maintained and then explode it and loop through it to access the other arrays; or you can try using patterns.  I'm thinking [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), but maybe another is a better fit.  This is using your second object as an example, but just add as many as needed:

```
class ContentAdapter {

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->obj->{$xmap[$name]};
    }
}    

class ContentAdapter_API_B extends ContentAdapter {

    public $xmap = ['bid' => 'BidPrice', 'ask' => 'AskPrice'];

    public function __construct($obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj->data;
    }
}
```

Now it is consistant regardless of the object since each has an adapter:

```
$content = new ContentAdapter_API_B($content);
echo $content->bid;
```

Using your first object you can either create a child as well (`ContentAdapter_API_A` in case the structure ever changes) or instantiate directly:

```
$content = new ContentAdapter($content);
echo $content->bid;
```

Or obviously just use it as is:

```
echo $content->bid;
```

An alternate way without inheritance is to use getters:

```
class ContentAdapter_API_B {

    public function __construct($obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj->data;
    }

    public function getBid() { return $this->obj->BidPrice; }
}
```

So long as the methods are consistent then it will always work:

```
$content = new ContentAdapter_API_B($content);
echo $content->getBid;
```